# React router not working properly and having trouble with the multiple routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a router like this

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/patient" component={Patient} />
  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route component={Landing}/>
</Switch>
```

It is working fine but when i add a route like this it throws an error

```
<Route path="/myuser/login" component={Login} />
```

The css is not applied properly and the error is like this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Even though i am loading the same component.

Comment: Can you share with us how you're navigating to that path? Specifically what is the URL that you enter to get to there?

Comment: Sure localhost:3000/myuser/login

Comment: you need to define a path for your final route: <Route path="/" component={Landing}/>

Comment: Did the same still it is not working